# CodeIgniter Invalid Driver Requested (Sessions)

Tags: codeigniter, session, user-data

I'm receiving the following error on all pages in a CodeIgniter application.

```
Invalid driver requested: Session_userdata
```

Does anyone have any idea what causes this? I don't seem to be able to find any information on this and can't seem to diagnose the issue.

The only thing I know is it's whenever the Session driver is loaded and I use session userdata.

Many thanks

Comment: show me the config.php session details

Comment: What version of CI are you using? `Session` is a **library** in <= 2.1.3, so if you are attempting to load it as a driver, that's incorrect.

Comment: I went with PHP standard sessions - I'm using GitHub recent version which uses it as a driver

Answer (score 0):

Even I was getting this error on one of my projects, where I was trying to upgrade the CodeIgniter V 1.0 to  CodeIgniter V 3.0.  It took few days for me to figure out the root cause and eventually I ended up with below steps to get rid of “***Invalid  Session_userdata***” error.

**Step 1:**

`$this->load->library('session')` should be replaced as `$this->load->driver('session');`

**Step: 2**

Accessing the session userdata array should be as follows,
Access userdata like this `$this->session->cookie->userdata[]` insted of `$this->session->userdata[]`

**Step 3:**

`$this->CI->session->userdata[]`   should be replaced as  `$this->CI->session->cookie->userdata[]`

**Step 4:**

Don't put echo before calling view file (Ex., `$this->load->view('some_view_file','');`)

**Step 5:**

Controllers, Models, Libraries file name should be started with Capital Letter, because it’s case sensitive.

If you want to know more about upgrading to  CodeIgniter V 3.0, refer below link:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html